# comparing longest streak of two persons OM and ADDY

Tags: arrays

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
  int t;
  do {
    scanf("%d", &t);
  } while (t < 1 || t > 100000);

  while (t--) {
    int n;
    do {
      scanf("%d", &n);
    } while (n < 1 || n > 100000);

    int a[n], b[n], count1 = 0, count2 = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      do {
        scanf("%d", &a[i]);
      } while (a[i] < 1 || a[i] > 1000000000);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      do {
        scanf("%d", &b[i]);
      } while (b[i] < 1 || b[i] > 1000000000);
    }

    int i = 0, one_streak1 = 0, one_streak2 = 0, temp = 0;
    while (i < n) {
      temp = 0;
      while (a[i] > 0) {
        temp = temp + 1;
        i = i + 1;
        if (i == n) {
          break;
        }
      }
      if (one_streak1 < temp) {
        one_streak1 = temp;
      }
      i = i + 1;
    }

    i = 0;
    while (i < n) {
      temp = 0;
      while (b[i] > 0) {
        temp = temp + 1;
        i = i + 1;
        if (i == n) {
          break;
        }
      }
      if (one_streak2 < temp) {
        one_streak2 = temp;
      }
      i = i + 1;
    }

    if (one_streak1 > one_streak2) {
      printf("OM\n");
    }
    else if (one_streak2 > one_streak1) {
      printf("ADDY\n");
    }
    else if (one_streak1 == one_streak2) {
      printf("DRAW\n");
   }
 }
}
```

```
testcase=1
n=6

a[]=1 7 3 0 2 13
b[]=0 2 3 4 5 0
```

was expecting `addy` but got `draw`

hello dear reader i am trying to get the person with most longest streak out of both addy and om, the streak gets reset if a 0 comes means player didn't did anything that day, but don't know why the answer is coming incorrect

Comment: And also read apply https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems

Comment: `while (a[i] < 1 || a[i] > 1000000000)` respectively `while (b[i] < 1 || b[i] > 1000000000)` does not allow you to read `0` from the input. So I wonder how you even get any output because with your testcase, the second `for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)`  loop (ie for reading all the `b[i]`)  won't complete because you run out of inputs